# How to install vim plugin in Windows 10?

Tags: command-line, installation, vim

I installed a vim.exe on my Windows machine. There isn't a .vim directory in my  home directory. How to install vim plugin in this case?

Answer (score 3):

If you installed vim with default settings from [vim.org](https://www.vim.org/), then home directory will be created in `C:\Users\user_name\vimfiles`. Where `user_name` is name of your windows user. I suggest you use [pathogen](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2332) as the easiest plugin manager. You just unpack plugin in `bundle` subdirectory of your home directory and it works.

As for second question about c++, i recommend ctags and cscope based plugins for navigation, autocompleters and snippets for fast coding, some useful tools for fast editing. Search for next plugins:

```
cctree, cscope_macros
easytags
OmniCppComplete, youcompleteme
taglist, tagbar
ultisnips/snipmate
fswitch
surround
unimpaired
```

Some of them requires long setup and even compilation (like youcompleteme) and python support, but give you more power. =) Good luck.